# Simplify a sum of indirect cell values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a relative Excel rookie trying to improve an old workbook, which has a formula along the lines of

```
(INDIRECT(C5)+INDIRECT(D5)+...+INDIRECT(AJ5)+INDIRECT(AK5))/60
```

and in a different place

```
(INDIRECT(C4)+INDIRECT(C5)+...+INDIRECT(C22)+INDIRECT(C23))/60
```

Can I simplify these somehow, e.g. by using range/array notation?

Comment: What types of values are in C5:AK5 and C4:C23?

Comment: Names of other cell names, which in turn contain plain numbers. 
Specifically, those ranges contain values such as "_A0", "_A1", "_B0" and so on; far to the right, there are cells *named* "_A0", "_A1", ... containing the length of a work shift (in minutes). The formulae then sum up the number of hours, both row-wise (for a single worker) and column-wise (for a single day, all workers combined).
(BTW, I didn't design the spreadsheet. :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with designing a whole new worksheet :)

Comment: You don't really give explanation what the Worksheet is, nor why you are using Indirect. Try this however: `=SUM(Indirect(c4:c23)/60)` or some derivation. Don't press enter when done; instead SHIFT + CNTRL + ENTER. Might work.

Comment: @ejbytes The worksheet is designed to schedule shifts for workers, and to ensure that the total work volume is equal to their pay grade, as well as to ensure that the number of scheduled workers at any given time is correct. The cells use INDIRECT to combine the main schedule sheet into a semi-human readable form (e.g. a value of _A2 referring to a 07:15-15:00 shift with a 30 min break) and a machine-calculable form, where Excel uses those indirect sums to find a worker's total weekly load as described in my last comment.
This system has been working well, so I don't think I should change it.

Comment: @exscape Did you try out the solution I offered? Just above your recent comment?

Comment: @ejbytes Oops, sorry. Yes, I tried it, but it doesn't work. INDIRECT doesn't seem to support working with arrays.

Comment: @exscape Ah, I forgot an extra SUM. Solution posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Can I simplify these somehow, e.g. by using range/array notation?
> ```

Yes.

Use this process:

```
=SUM(SUM(INDIRECT(C4:C23)))/60
```

Then after entering the data, press <kbd>SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER</kbd>

When entering data correctly, Excel will include braces (eg {...})
[image]

Comment: @exscape Glad it worked out!