# Simplify a Vstack of Indirect Cell Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to combine tables across several different sheets, where each sheet represents a PO and has a table of associated invoices. The number of sheets is variable, and will get longer as each project goes on, but is based on a template so I can have a helper cell that contains the table name for that sheet.

I want to create a summary table that has all the invoices in one place, and believe the 'VSTACK()' function should work for this.

I already have a summary table of each PO (an array formula finds the sheet names, and a series of `VLOOKUP()` the values), so I currently have a hidden column there which contains the name of the table in each sheet.

[image: snip showing the hidden column that contains the table names]

I tried the below formulas:

```
=VSTACK(INDIRECT(N8:N140))
```

and

```
=VSTACK(TOCOL(INDIRECT(N8:N140),3))
=TOCOL(VSTACK(INDIRECT(N8:N140)),3)
```

However this returns a `#VALUE!` error for each sheet that has a reference, and a `#REF!` error otherwise.

What does work is manually filling each row like the below:

```
=VSTACK(INDIRECT(N8),INDIRECT(N9),INDIRECT(N10),...)
```

But I'd rather not have to fill this out manually.

I came across this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1196243/simplify-a-sum-of-indirect-cell-values?newreg=952b547b3d004342b25aeca15c41c9b1), which has a similar problem, but while the solution there works for the `SUM()` function, it doesn't work for the `VSTACK()` function

Is it possible to simplify a `VSTACK()` that contains indirect references?

Comment: One comment, If these all point to a different workbook, all those workbooks will need to be open for INDIRECT to work otherwise one would get the `#REF` error.

Comment: This is all contained within the same workbook, just different sheets.
I currently have it working with my manual indirect method (+ an 'iferror'), but I'd like to replace it with something a bit more readable & easier to debug if an issue arises.